# Posting only select values from form created with a while loop

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, submit

I am very new to HTML and SQL so everything I am doing is self taught through this and other online sites.   I create a number of forms based on the number of entries in my database.  This number can vary up approximately 50 entries.  Essentially, what I want to do is create a submit button that posts three pieces of information to a second database.  These pieces of information are the part number (always a unique value), the cure time, and the press number.  I know part of my problem is giving values unique names so the submit knows what data it is to be using, but I cannot seem to figure out the proper format.  For the time being, I only want to pass the $partnum variable to the second database.  I can reverse engineer backward from there to get the rest.

PHP code

```
function press_list($partnum)
{
    echo "<select name=\"Press_used".$partnum."\"style=\"float:right\">";
    echo "<option selected>---</option>";
    echo "<option value =\"A1-T\">A1-T</option>";
    ... <-- other options omitted to save space
    echo "<option value =\"A10-B\">A10-B</option>";
    echo "</select>";
}
function load_button($cureleft)
{
   if ($cureleft <= 0)
   {
       echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Loading\" />";
   }
   else
   {
       echo "<input type=\"submit\" value=\"Loading\" disabled>";
   }

}
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   $partnum = $row['Part_Number'];
   echo "<form action=\"loadpost.php\" name=\"".$row['Part_Number']."\">";
   echo "<fieldset>";
   echo "<h3>".$row['Part_Number']."</h3>";
   echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$partnum."\" value=\"".$partnum."\">";
   echo "<p class=\"center\">".$row['New_#']."</p>";
   echo "<p class=\"center\">Size: <b>".$row['Tire_Size']."</b></p>";   
   echo "<p class=\"leftalign\">Tread: ";
   echo $row['Type_&_Tread'];
   $weight=number_format($row['Build_Weight'],1);
   echo "<span class=\"rightalign\">Weight: ".$weight."</span></p>";
   echo "<p class=\"box\">--Notes--";
   echo "<br><span class=\"center\">".$row['NOTES']."</span></p>";
   echo "<p class=\"leftalign\">Scheduled Press: ";
   echo $row['Press'];
   press_list($partnum);
   echo "</p>";
   echo "<p class=\"leftalign\">Cure time: ";
   echo ($row['Cure_Time']*60);
   $cureleft = (($row['Cure_Time']*60)-190);
   echo "<span class=\"rightalign\">Cure left: ".$cureleft."</span></p>";
   load_button($cureleft);
   echo "</fieldset>";
   echo "</form>
   ";
}

mysqli_close($con);
```

?>

Loadpost.php

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","admin","floortracking");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

  $sql="INSERT INTO loaded (Cure, Time, Tire, Press)
VALUES ('53',now(),'$_POST[$partnum]','$_POST[Press_used]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
echo "<p>1 record added</p>";
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

One form HTML

```
<form action="loadpost.php" name="01-590905-001R"><fieldset><h3>01-590905-001R</h3><input type="hidden" name="partnum" value="01-590905-001R"><p class="center">20005133</p><p class="center">Size: <b>RECLAIM</b></p><p class="leftalign">Tread: BO2K<span class="rightalign">Weight: 56.0</span></p><p class="box">--Notes--<br><span class="center">RECLAIM</span></p><p class="leftalign">Scheduled Press: A1-T<select name="Press_used" style="float:right"><option selected>---</option><option value ="A1-T">A1-T</option><option value ="A1-M">A1-M</option><option value ="A1-B">A1-B</option><option value ="A2-T">A2-T</option><option value ="A2-B">A2-B</option><option value ="A3-T">A3-T</option><option value ="A3-M">A3-M</option><option value ="A3-B">A3-B</option><option value ="A4-T">A4-T</option><option value ="A4-B">A4-B</option><option value ="A5-T">A2-T</option><option value ="A5-B">A2-B</option><option value ="A6">A6</option><option value ="A7-T">A7-T</option><option value ="A7-B">A7-B</option><option value ="A8-T">A8-T</option><option value ="A8-B">A8-B</option><option value ="A9-T">A9-T</option><option value ="A9-B">A9-B</option><option value ="A10-T">A10-T</option><option value ="A10-B">A10-B</option></select></p><p class="leftalign">Cure time: 180<span class="rightalign">Cure left: -10</span></p><input type="submit" value="Loading" ></fieldset></form>
```

Comment: You only have the select, the submit button, and the hidden input fields for the form? How the user inputs the 3 necessery fields? Could you show a sample html code, I could try?

Comment: If I comprehended your description right, you would like to use only 1 submit button which submits only one of the 50 forms, which is selected by you <select> field. Is it right?

Comment: That is correct.  The only value that the user has to alter is the select option.  The other two values are simply used for identification inside the second database.

Comment: I keep re-reading trying to figure out how best to answer your question.  I think some background on this would be best.  I am trying to develop a screen that the operators on the factory floor at my plant will be using.  They need all the shown information to know which tire to load.  The only thing that may be varying is the press it will be loaded into.  The tire number is the unique value we will use for reporting, and the cure time is at present just the calculated value, $cureleft.  In the future that information will be taken from another database.

Comment: I'm almost sure you will have to use javascript in this case. I'm trying to write you one code, but I'm not sure if I'm really solving your problem. I screenshoot or the generated source code would help.

Comment: I would like to have a unique submit button at the end of each form that submits the information for that form only.

Comment: I just realized you have more than one select. One for every part number in the list. I was thinking it only shows itself once, so now I'm sure I was working on a 'different' problem

Comment: oh that sounds MUCH easier than I thought.

Comment: Poor user that has to press up to 50 submit-buttons :-)

Comment: Well he will be pressing one button at a time as he loads the tire.

Comment: I'm still not understanding your question. Are you talking about 50 *forms* or up to 50 *form-elements*? If you only need 3 pieces from the form, just build the form around those 3, and display everything else as a table or so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First

You have to change
this

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"".$partnum."\" value=\"".$partnum."\">";
```

to this

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name='partnum' value=\"".$partnum."\">";
```

Since you have one submit button inside of each form, they will submit the form they are inside of. You don't have to worry about submitting the right form. There won't be any other input field submitted which is not inside of that form, you are submitting from

Second

You don't need to echo the partnum inside every select

Change this

```
echo "<select name=\"Press_used".$partnum."\"style=\"float:right\">";
```

into this

```
echo "<select name=\"Press_used\"style=\"float:right\">";
```

Thirdly, the sql

```
$sql="INSERT INTO loaded (Cure, Time, Tire, Press)
VALUES ('53',now(),'$_POST[$partnum]','$_POST[Press_used]')";

$sql="INSERT INTO loaded (Cure, Time, Tire, Press)
VALUES ('53',now(),'".$_POST['partnum']."','".$_POST["Press_used"]."')";
```

I think that's all

Update:

This:

```
echo "<form action=\"loadpost.php\" name=\"".$row['Part_Number']."\">";
```

Into this:

```
echo "<form action=\"loadpost.php\" name=\"".$row['Part_Number']."\" method='POST'>";
```

Comment: Tell me if this works, or something went wrong, or if you need any further explanation

Comment: That was how I originally had everything set up.  I have reverted back and matched the format you use.  Thank you for clarification on the submit submitting only the form it is inside of.  I am getting a blank field inside of the database though.  I attached the HTML of the revised code above.

Comment: could you please echo the $sql, and var_dump($_REQUEST)?

Comment: echoed $sql -->  INSERT INTO loaded (Cure, Time, Tire, Press) VALUES ('53',now(),'','')

Comment: could you please also var_dump($_REQUEST)?

Comment: oh! You are using $_POST but your <form> method is not set to Post

Comment: array(2) { ["partnum"]=> string(14) "01-590905-001R" ["Press_used"]=> string(3) "---" }

Comment: You're partnum, and press_used are in the get array, but not in the post array. This is why I always use the request array (bad practise or not), because it's always get into that both post, and get

Comment: That worked, I just noticed the method on the form.  Values are being passed correctly now.  Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at your $_Post-Array in Loadpost.php.

> I know part of my problem is giving values unique names

Correct. Alter the name properties of the input/select fields in your form. Use only static names.

```
echo "<input type=\"hidden\" name=\"partnum\" value=\"".$partnum."\">";
```

and

```
echo "<select name=\"Press_used\"style=\"float:right\">";
```

Loadpost.php:

Now you can access the values in $_POST:

```
$_POST['partnum']
$_POST['Press_used']
```

Comment: When I do that, it ends up passing a blank value to the database. I thought that with each loop, I would need to name each field something new.  Since the partnumbers never duplicate, I was choosing to use that for names.

Comment: I missed `method='POST'` in the form tag. But @LaczkoUr already mentioned it.